# Fetching Access token using Auth token from service in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, access-token, auth-token

I am new to the topic of Oauth and encryption. I need to write a utility where I have authtoken with me and I need to get access token after making a call to the service url say xyzcorp.com. I already have auth token with me I need to use post method to make service call to the url which in turn returns access token. I couldn't find any code snippet which shows how this is done. As I already said I am a newbie into this area, don't have any clue about the implementation in c#. It should be noted that I only have auth token with me.

Answer (score 0):

What C# library are you using? I used Thinktecture.IdentityModel:
https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel

Here's an example from my [OAuth2 Test Client](https://github.com/Excape/oAuth2TestClient), using IdentityModel:

```
private static async Task<TokenResponse> SendTokenRequest(string authCode, string redirectUri)
    {
        var tokenclient = new OAuth2Client(
            new Uri(Constant.TokenEndpoint),
            Constant.CodeClientId,
            Constant.CodeClientSecret);


        return await tokenclient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(authCode, redirectUri);
    }
```